# ASP.NET dynamic user interface OR form designer

Tags: asp.net

I need to create an application that allows users to design forms for various purposes. basically users should be able to design a form just like developers can do it in design mode using Visual studio (drag and drop controls and add data). for example users should be able to create a set of questions for a survey and as part of questionnaire, they should be able to select various controls and create a template for the questionnaire and save it down in the database, which could then be used by other set of users who actually need to answer that questionnaire. Is this possible to achieve? is there any component that does this already? any help will be appreciated. thanks. Please let me know if the question is not clear, I can add more detail.

Comment: This is possible. Webparts and AJAX could well be part of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first that crossed my mind are [ASP.Net WebParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Have a look at some Tutorials about Webparts and [Personalization](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/webparts/personalization.aspx).
I've never developed what you want but i think Webparts with Ajax would be the best way and is worth to spend time on.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply, I heard about web parts before (igoogle), but I didn't know user can design a complete form with various controls using it. I just know users can drag and drop the widgets and may be change the size. to clarify, there are two set of users here. one who designs the form for a specific requirement and the template is saved in database and other users can only fill in the form and submit the information, they can't change the form design. hope it is clear.

Comment: Couldn't you create form element widgets?  And have buttons that create a new instance of a widget when pressed?  Like a button that says "Add Text Field" and then it is clicked - a text field widget instance appears and they can drag & drop it where they want using the Web Parts functionality.

Comment: If users can see the "Designer-View" or the normal view depends of your authorisation system. There are no Out-of-the-box controls that i know which do all the work for you. I think there is a lot of work for you, but i think that Webparts are still the best way.